# Http compatible dealing with data transmission and error handling using jquery ajax requests

Tags: c#, rest, jquery, exception, http-headers

I'm wondering how should look the correct way of dealing with data transmission and handling errors using latest jquery ajax requests with http compatible approach.

I've noticed, that when unhandled exception occurs at server side, and I **did not specify** the data type I'm expecting in http protocol, the **success** method invokes and the client receives 200 OK response, as if nothing wrong happend:

```
$.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsondata,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            // i'm here now
        },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
        }
});
```

[image]

[image]

If I **specify** type, that I'm expecting for exaple json, an ajax **error** function invokes. It's because stack trace is not serialized by default to json, so parsing will fail:

```
$.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsondata,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
            // but now I'm here
        }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Now it's also 200 OK, but an error (not success) is invoked.

What is the better way to cope with exception handling. Should I specify the type, which is more RESTFull in my opinion, or just let it be unspecified, and always jump into success ?

Should I always wrap ajax method at the server side in `try{}catch(){}` block, and pass error of appropriate type, the client asks me to return ?

```
[HttpPost]
public NJsonResult Execute()
{
    try
    {
        // do some logic if you do not mind
        if (success)
        {
             return new NJsonResult(new {status = "success"});
        }
        return new NJsonResult(new { status = "error" });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return new NJsonResult(new { status = "error" });        
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: action,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsondata,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == "success") {
        }
        else (data.status == "error") {
        }
    }
```

Mabye should I always care of predictable errors and don't care about exceptions, and did not specify any type ?

```
[HttpPost]
public NJsonResult Execute()
{
    // do some logic if you do not mind
    if (success)
    {
        return new NJsonResult(new {status = "success"});
    }
    return new NJsonResult(new { status = "error" });
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: action,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == "success") {
        }
        else {
            // handle even exceptions, because content-type in not specified
        }
    }
});
```

Where is the place for error function and correct http status codes (not always 200 OK)

Now, I've implemented a global hook for intercepting unhandled exceptions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
            // handle it if you dare
        }
    });    
});
```

and always specify the **content-type** and **accept** headers, using **contentType** and **dataType** ajax properties. I do not use `try{}catch{}` block - I don't care about logic abnormal behavior. I just log it in **Global.asax** and pass it further to the response.

So, as in the first lines of this question, what is the best approach ? Any other ideas ?